# Hive transformation

Tags: hive, klout

I am trying to make a simple hive transformation.

[image: Simple Hive Transformation]

Can some one provide me a way to do this? I have tried collect_set and currently looking at klout's open source UDF.

Comment: There can be same units later on e.g. ABC can start come at Date-time 8 and followed by PAR at date-time 9. we need to maintain the time - unit continuum. Fyi, a simple groupby would make this incorrect pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives you what you want.  I wasn't able to run it and debug it though.  Good luck!

```
select start_point.unit
  , start_time as start
  , start_time + min(stop_time - start_time) as stop
from
  (select * from 
      (select date_time as start_time
        , unit
        , last_value(unit) over (order by date_time row desc between current row and 1 following) as previous_unit
      from table
      ) previous
      where unit <> previous_unit
  ) start_points
left outer join
  (select * from 
      (select date_time as stop_time
        , unit
        , last_value(unit) over (order by date_time row between current row and 1 following) as next_unit
      from table
      ) next
      where unit <> next_unit
  ) stop_points
on start_points.unit = stop_points.unit
where stop_time > start_time
group by start_point.unit, start_time
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on using windowing functions. Not an exact solve but on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the min and max functions? I think the following will get you what you need:

```
SELECT
    Unit,
    MIN(datetime) as start,
    MAX(datetime) as stop
from table_name
group by Unit
;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is not that straight forward. Imagine with different dates and time zones. More than one visits to same unit.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Thanks for the pointer to use window functions

```
select *
from
(select *, 
case when lag(unit,1) over (partition by id order by effective_time_ut desc) is NULL THEN 1 
when unit<>lag(unit,1) over (partition by id order by effective_time_ut desc) then 1 
when lead(unit,1) over (partition by id order by effective_time_ut desc) is NULL then 1
else 0 end as different_loc
from units_we_care) a
where different_loc=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temptable as select unit, start_date, end_time, row_number () over() as row_num from (select unit, min(date_time) start_date, max(date_time) as end_time from table group by unit) a;

select a.unit, a.start_date as start_date, nvl(b.start_date, a.end_time) end_time from temptable a left outer join temptable b on (a.row_num+1) = b.row_num;
```